# How to run atmosphere example

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

I have downloaded the example from this [link](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-The-Atmosphere-Framework-and-WebSocket) and I created the web application based on Tomcat, but one thing confused me is **how to run that program?**  Seems there is no main function to run

Answer (score 1):

Web-applications do not run by themselves. You need to package them correctly as a `war` and deploy them on an application server, such as [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Normally, to deploy an application on Tomcat, you just need to copy the war into the webapps directory (wherever Tomcat is installed) and start Tomcat (if it is not already running).

You might have to add/change some additional configuration in Tomcat to make it work. I don't have any experience with the Atmosphere application, so I can't help you there, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809880/how-do-i-configure-tomcat-and-haproxy-to-work-with-the-websocket-framework-atmos?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146274/atmosphere-socket-established-but-no-data-being-received-sent?rq=1) stackoverflow questions looks relevant. If you run into trouble and can't figure it out from existing answers to these or other similar questions, you should probably ask a new question where you include the details.